# How to open share dialog from mobile website(not app)?

Tags: javascript, mobile

[image]

I didn't find any options. there is any way to do it?

Comment: I guess you can't control that window.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be interested in this : https://simplesharebuttons.com/html-share-buttons/